# https://example.com/app/login to https://example.com/app/#/login

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have an HTML5 react app and I want all routes that come after /app/
to be redirected to /app/#/

I want this to be achieved with .htaccess

I've tried this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/app/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)?$ /#/$1 [NE,R]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/[a-z]+
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /app/#/$1 [L,NE,R]
```